# Concurrency-safe templates in Go: How do I do it?

Tags: go, templates, concurrency

I have the following call:

```
import (
  "text/template"
)

//...

template.New(filepath.Base(name)).Funcs(templateFunctions).Parse(string(asset))
```

which is called in several Go routines concurrently,
which in turn causes the following panic:

```
fatal error: concurrent map iteration and map write
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
goroutine 140 [running]:
text/template.addValueFuncs(0xc00188e000?, 0xc00188e000?)
        [...]/go/src/text/template/funcs.go:88 +0x76
[...]/modules/template.loadEmbeddedTemplates({0x38ff6cb?, 0xc001cf8060?})
        [...]/src/modules/template/configBased.go:163 +0x749
```

The line on `src/modules/template/configBased.go:163`
quoted above. It is `template.New(...)`.

The surrounding function is called from goroutines concurrently.

That is the code from `go/src/text/template/funcs.go:88` is it helps:

```
// addValueFuncs adds to values the functions in funcs, converting them to reflect.Values.
func addValueFuncs(out map[string]reflect.Value, in FuncMap) {
    for name, fn := range in {
        if !goodName(name) {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("function name %q is not a valid identifier", name))
        }
        v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
        if v.Kind() != reflect.Func {
            panic("value for " + name + " not a function")
        }
        if !goodFunc(v.Type()) {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("can't install method/function %q with %d results", name, v.Type().NumOut()))
        }
        out[name] = v
    }
}
```

If `template.New` is concurrent-safe, why this line produces this panic, and how am I supposed to handle it properly?

**Update.**

The code of the nasty function `loadEmbeddedTemplates`:

```
func loadEmbeddedTemplates(templateFile string) (*template.Template, error) {
    var t *template.Template

    templateFile = filepath.Join("share", "templates", filepath.Base(templateFile))
    dir := filepath.Dir(templateFile)
    names := assets.GetAssetNames()

    // All templates except + the last one at the end
    filteredNames := []string{}

    for _, name := range names {
        if !strings.HasPrefix(name, dir+"/") || !strings.HasSuffix(name, ".tmpl") {
            continue
        }

        if name != templateFile {
            filteredNames = append(filteredNames, name)
        }
    }

    filteredNames = append(filteredNames, templateFile)

    for _, name := range filteredNames {
        asset, err := assets.GetAsset(name)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if t == nil {
            t, err = template.New(filepath.Base(name)).Funcs(templateFunctions).Parse(string(asset))
        } else {
            t, err = t.New(filepath.Base(name)).Parse(string(asset))
        }

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return t, nil
}
```

The function simply loads all templates from `share/templates/` one after another

Comment: Just like any other shared value, you serialize access to it. Usually you only parse a template once though, why are you concurrently creating the same template? (from the docs: _"Because associated templates share underlying data, template construction cannot be done safely in parallel. Once the templates are constructed, they can be executed in parallel."_)

Comment: @JimB: `Usually you only parse a template once though, why are you concurrently creating the same template?` Because I am doing it in a function that is called in parallel. I don't really want to recreate them if they are already there, but how can I use them properly?

Comment: But you are recreating them, just do it once and store the result, then you can execute them concurrently.

Comment: @JimB: You mean, in some global variable?

Comment: @JimB: what I can't understand, what two templates, which I create fully independently in two different function calls, share with each other? Do they have some global state to share?

Comment: It could also be in your `templateFunctions`. The stack trace from the from the concurrent map write or the race detector will show you exactly where the problem starts (also would help to know exactly what `Template.New()` is, do you mean `template.New` from `html/template`?)

Comment: @JimB: Sorry, it was a typo; `template`, not `Template`; ad yes, it is `text/template`

Comment: `template.New()` is safe for concurrent use. The error comes from code which you haven't showed, likely you storing the result in a map. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @icza: I've updated the question. From the backtrace, it is clearly visible that I do something else wrong, but not modifying a map concurrently. I call `template.New` in many go routines simultaneously, and it seems to trigger the problem

Comment: Your stack trace shows `loadEmbeddedTemplates()` does something nasty. Show its code, or better, show a [mcve].

Comment: @icza: added `loadEmbeddedTemplates`; as you can see it is absolutely harmless

Comment: If you use the race detector it would show you all the corresponding read and write locations, making it easier to pinpoint where you are missing synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loadEmbeddedTemplates()` function accesses the `templateFunctions` variable, passes it to `Template.Funcs()` which will obviously read it (will iterate over it).

And you are likely populating it concurrently, in another goroutine. Hence the concurrent map write error. Access to it must be synchronized.

If possible, populate it first, and only after that start using it (passing it to `Template.Funcs()`). That way no additional synchronization or locking will be required (concurrent read only is always OK).